# Iterate list through a function keep returning Nonetype

Tags: python, list, tuples, data-science

So I was trying to iterate this list `techno_list1 = ["C", "C#", "C++", "Java",  "JavaScript", "Python", "Scala", "Oracle", "SQL Server", "MySQL Server", "PostgreSQL", "MongoDB"]`
through a function that return the number of job related to the keyword inside the list below is the function:

```html
def get_number_of_jobs(technology):
    number_of_jobs = 0
    page=0
    new_results=1
    while new_results>0:
        paras={"description":technology,"page":page}
        r=requests.get(baseurl,paras)
        new_results=len(r.json())
        page+=1
        number_of_jobs+=(len(r.json()))
         
    return technology,number_of_jobs
```

It return a tuple like this `('C', 239) ('C#', 50) ('C++', 32) ('Java', 138) ('JavaScript', 116) ('Python', 98) ('Scala', 94) ('Oracle', 18) ('SQL Server', 28) ('MySQL Server', 14) ('PostgreSQL', 22) ('MongoDB', 14)`
So I thought it should be a tuple but when checking using type() it keep returning `<class 'NoneType'>`

I want it to be either List or Tuple is there anyway to change the data type ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code which: `when checking using type()`

Comment: The function shown has exactly one return path; it *cannot* return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I encountered:

```html
techno_list1 = ["C", "C#", "C++", "Java",  "JavaScript", "Python", "Scala", "Oracle", "SQL Server", "MySQL Server", "PostgreSQL", "MongoDB"]
def number_of_each(techno_list):
    for x in techno_list:
        print(get_number_of_jobs(x))
print(type(number_of_each(techno_list1)))
```

Then the result:

```html
('C', 239)
('C#', 50)
('C++', 32)
('Java', 138)
('JavaScript', 116)
('Python', 98)
('Scala', 94)
('Oracle', 18)
('SQL Server', 28)
('MySQL Server', 14)
('PostgreSQL', 22)
('MongoDB', 14)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Maybe it a bug ?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  If you have additional details to add, they should be edited into the original question.  (And the only bug here is your belief that `number_of_each()` is capable of returning anything other than None, given that it contains no `return` statement.)

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new here, and thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

From you extended elaboration, I can see that you are printing the type of `number_of_each(techno_list1)`.

However, this function is currently not returning anything, it simply just prints out the values you obtained through `get_number_of_jobs()`. This is why it is returning `<class 'NoneType'>`.

I would create a list outside of the function `number_of_each()` and then add the items to the list to print out later, try this:

```html
techno_list1 = ["C", "C#", "C++", "Java",  "JavaScript", "Python", "Scala", "Oracle", "SQL Server", "MySQL Server", "PostgreSQL", "MongoDB"]
job_numb = []

def number_of_each(techno_list):
    for x in techno_list:
        job_numb.append(get_number_of_jobs(x))
        print(type(get_number_of_jobs(x))

print(job_numb)
```

The type being printed now should be `<class 'list'>` for `job_numb` and `<class 'tuple'>` for the return of `get_number_of_jobs()` or any items in `job_numb`.

Realistically, this does not really change anything. You already have a tuple returned by the `get_number_of_jobs()` function. You are just misprinting the right variable.